# colorRampPalette in R more than 2 clusters

Tags: r, colors, cluster-analysis

I'd want to color my points with different colors in a fuzzy way, according to a probabilistic function associated to the points.

I've managed for 2 cases. First I'm building my dataset and a probabilities associated given 2 clusters.

```
set.seed(16)
rbPal <- colorRampPalette(c('yellow','red')) 
(mu1<-c(0,0))                  # vector mean multinom 1
(S1<-matrix(c(0.1,0,0,0.6),2)) # var/cov matrix multinom 1
(mu2<-c(3,0))                  # vector mean multino 2
(S2<- matrix(c(1,0,0,0.1),2))  # var/cov matrix multinom 2

x1<-mvrnorm(n=100, mu=mu1,Sigma=S1 )
x2<-mvrnorm(n=100, mu=mu2,Sigma=S2 )

x<-rbind(x1,x2)              # Dataset

euc.dist<-function (a,b){
sqrt(sum((a-b)^2))
}

randC<-x[sample(nrow(x),2),]
Distmatrix<- t(apply(x,1,function(r) apply(randC,1, function(s) euc.dist(r, 
s))))
mat<-matrix(,200,2)
mat<-apply(mat,2,function(x) x=apply(Distmatrix,1, prod))/Distmatrix

P<-t(apply(mat, 1, function(x) x/sum(x)))
D4<-data.frame(x,P)

D4$Col <- rbPal(10)[as.numeric(cut(D4$X1.1,breaks = 10))]


plot(D4$X1,D4$X2,pch = 20,col = D4$Col, cex=1.2) 
points(randC, col="red")
```

[image: Ex]

That's what I get imagining 2 points as centroid of a cluster.

What if I wanted to do the same color job imagining more than 2 clusters?

So I should have:

```
[...]
set.seed(50)
rbPal <- colorRampPalette(c('yellow','red',"green"))
mat<-matrix(,200,3) 
randC<-x[sample(nrow(x),3),]
Distmatrix<- t(apply(x,1,function(r) apply(randC,1, function(s) euc.dist(r, 
s))))

mat<-apply(mat,2,function(x) x=apply(Distmatrix,1, prod))/Distmatrix

P<-t(apply(mat, 1, function(x) x/sum(x)))
D4<-data.frame(x,P)

D4$Col <- rbPal(10)[as.numeric(cut(D4$X1.1,breaks = 10))]


plot(D4$X1,D4$X2,pch = 20,col = D4$Col, cex=1.2) 
points(randC, col="red")
```

[image]

That's wrong, cause I want that each centroid has the maximum value for a color and then shade according to the distance depending on which cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a good solution, here's the cose:

```
set.seed(50)
mat<-matrix(,200,3) 
randC<-x[sample(nrow(x),3),]
Distmatrix<- t(apply(x,1,function(r) apply(randC,1, function(s) euc.dist(r, 
                                                                         s))))

mat<-apply(mat,2,function(x) x=apply(Distmatrix,1, prod))/Distmatrix

P<-t(apply(mat, 1, function(x) x/sum(x)))
D4<-data.frame(x,P)


rbPal<-list()
for(i in 1:k){
  rbPal[[i]] <- colorRampPalette(c('white',col=I(i+1)))
}
for(i in 1:k){
  D4[[dim(D4)[2]+1]] <- rbPal[[i]](10)[as.numeric(cut(D4[[2+i]],breaks = 10))]
}


for(i in 1:k){
  D4[[dim(D4)[2]+1]]<-t(col2rgb(D4[[dim(D4)[2]-k+1]])) 
}

prova<-matrix(0,dim(D4)[1],3)
for(i in 1:k){
  prova<-prova+D4[,(dim(D4)[2]-k+i)]*P[,i]
}
prova[is.nan(prova)] <- 0
provcol=apply(prova,1, function(x) rgb(x[1], x[2], x[3], maxColorValue=255))
plot(D4$X1,D4$X2,pch = 20,col = provcol, cex=1.5) 
points(randC, col="red")
```

I basically created k different color palette each of them starting from white, which is the color in common of everybody. Then, according to probabilities, I mixed the rgb values of the k cluster probabilities with a weighted mixing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may need to do the mixing function yourself.

If you have more than two clusters, a linear color space is not enough anymore.

The easiest choice is a linear mixing in each component. Straight forward to implement. For more advanced cases, you may want "balanced" points (where all distances are equal) to be gray, and not the average color.

As an ad-hoc solution, you could also set up palettes for each cluster, from gray to the clusters color. Then use (x_j-x_i)/x_j of the ith palette as value, where x_i is the smallest, and x_j the second smallest value. If x_i=x_j, the value will be 0 (gray). If x_i=0, the value will be 1.

This is probably quite pretty, but can be misleading because it doesn't use the same scaling everywhere.